# Remove div by class not containing "X" under specific path/xpath

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, xpath

```
<div id="container-main" name="#top">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div id="view" ui-view="" autoscroll="" class="ng-scope">
      <div ng-include="template == 'hover' ? 'templates/hover.html' : null" class="ng-scope">
        <div class="chart-wrap--hover clearfix ng-scope">

          <div class="card--sml card--hover ng-scope fff" > Keep </div>
          <div class="card--sml card--hover ng-scope" > Remove </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using Javascript/Tampermonkey I want to remove div that doesn't have `"fff"` in their class that's only from a specific path so it doesn't remove all other irrelative divs.

Is there a way to work with Xpaths in js ? I need to remove div except class `"fff"` on `xpath: //*[@id="view"]/div[1]/div`

I've tried several things and searched for it however, I couldn't solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your starting point is id="view" you are more than 2 levels deep to find .fff:

```
$('#view > div:first > div > div:not(.fff)').remove()
```

if you don't want the first top level div remove `first` or use `eq(n)` to target specific children.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/cn5xxjne/

Answer (score 1):

why not use a simple css selector:

Ok as @trueaussie suggested this will remove any div that doesn't have a "fff" in the string 
so it will also leave

```
class="testclassnamefff"
class="ffftestclassname"
class="ghjgfffjfkfjkf"
```

```js
$('#view  div:first  div div:not([class*=fff])').remove();
```

```css
[class*=fff] {
    border: 5px solid yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container-main" name="#top">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
    <div id="view" ui-view="" autoscroll="" class="ng-scope">
      <div ng-include="template == 'hover' ? 'templates/hover.html' : null" class="ng-scope">
        <div class="chart-wrap--hover clearfix ng-scope">

          <div class="card--sml card--hover ng-scope fff" > Keep </div>
          
          <div class="card--sml card--hover ng-scope dhjdhjdfff" > Keep </div>
          
          <div class="card--sml card--hover ng-scope fffdkldkld" > Keep </div>
          
          <div class="card--sml card--hover ng-scope dsdssdsdfffdsdd" > Keep </div>
          <div class="card--sml card--hover ng-scope" > Remove </div>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/79qu7k4e/1/

Comment: He said _only from a specific path_, meaning only within the `view` DIV.

Comment: `[class*=fff]` will match any class that *contains* fff. e.g. `fffff`, `blaffff` etc. That is not what they wanted.

Comment: " I want to remove div that doesn't have "fff" in their class" 
this will match any selector that does not have fff in there class

Comment: Also "need to remove div except class "fff"... The grammar was wrong... They meant in the class (as in the entire class string)

Comment: there you may be right mate but that's not what they asked for :D

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery:

```
$("#view > div:eq(1) > div > div:not(.fff)").remove();
```

Comment: The structure is actually deeper than the existing code hints at.

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: Looking at the HTML? :) It is one more level than the code specifies :> The HTML is now formatted.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting from TrueBlueAussie's previous answer:

```
$("#view > div:first > div > div:not(.fff)").remove();
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/pnrhLjk9/